# Compare destination files with source files delete only the copied files. New files being added every 5 minutes in source directory/subfolders

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell 
I have the following code in powershell
Files are being moved from an AS400 Server to the \ServerZoro\AS400 folder and #200 subfolders.

AS400 Admin says his side is working

From the Zoro server to the Sharepoint 2013 server files are being copied into #200 individuals folders (they are sales reports)

The Sharepoint code is working perfectly and not included here.

The problem is:
The as400 server constantly pushes new files into \Serverzoro\AS400 folder and #subfolders (when the script is running)

I need some powershell code to:
1) compare destination files with source (?) before deleting only the copied #files so that when new files are being added they are not deleted.

THe script runs every 15 minutes, I have set it now to 30 minutes.

The Sharepoint side works perfectly its just the above code I am having an issue with. as randomly a salesperson is missing a report

One week its 4 people missing 4 reports.

Next week its 1 person missing one report

Today it was 4 salesmen missing 4 total reports.

Help appreciated!!!

```
$SourceReportDump = "\\ServerZoro\as400"
# Drive X below goes into the sp2013 server perfectly
$TargetReportDump = "x:"

$IncludeFiles = ("*.pdf","*.xls","*.xlsx","*.txt")

$WebUrl = "http://sp2013.sitename.com/sites/reports"

$DocLibraryName = "AS400Reports"

$DocLibraryUrlName = "AS400Reports"

#Move reports into Sharepoint

$CopyReports = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceReportDump | Copy-Item            -Destination $TargetReportDump -Recurse  

$MoveReports = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceReportDump -Recurse -include            $IncludeFiles | sort datemodified -Descending | select -Skip 65 | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Please don't shout.

Comment: `select -Skip 65` jumps out. Hardcoded values are bound to give problems sooner or later. Why 65? Why do you think it's always 65?

Comment: Sorry, the number 65 is just random -didn't mean to 'shout' ; new to posting. Is there a way to "loop through" each report, move the reports, and check the original before deleting the original?

Answer (score 1):

use move command and not copy + delete (If your copy work and your delete doesnt work ? )

just like this

```
$SourceReportDump = '\\ServerZoro\as400'
$TargetReportDump = 'x:'
$IncludeFiles = ("*.pdf","*.xls","*.xlsx","*.txt")

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceReportDump -file -Recurse -include $IncludeFiles | %{$newpath=$_.DirectoryName -Replace [regex]::escape($SourceReportDump),$TargetReportDump;  if ($newpath -ne $TargetReportDump) {new-item -ItemType Directory  -path  $newpath -Force} ; move-item $_.FullName "$newpath\$($_.Name)" -Force  }
```

Comment: The issue is AS400 is constantly dumping reports into the source report dump location. When the powershell script runs sometimes a report is missed being copied and is deleted. I need a 'for each report loop' line of code to check source file, and move it... and not delete new reports that are populating when the script is running...thanks